# The main view of TodayVewController shifts right

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, widget

I'm adding a widget to my existing app and when i add a label to the main view of TodayVewController and run my app and then view the notification center it appears shifted to the right !

[image]
[image]

any idea how to fix this issue .. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a default margin set for the today view. That is why it is shifted to the left. You can override the default by implementing

```
- (UIEdgeInsets)widgetMarginInsetsForProposedMarginInsets:(UIEdgeInsets)defaultMarginInsets{
        defaultMarginInsets.left = 0;

        return defaultMarginInsets;
 }
```

See here : [App Extension Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/NotificationCenter.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH11-SW5)